# MariaDBのダンプの取得と復元について

Tags: mariadb

EC2上のMariaDBの全データーベースのダンプを取得して、新しく作成したEC2のMariaDB上で復元することでデータ移行を行いたいと考えています。この時のダンプの取得と復元に必要なコマンドを教えてください。また、新規のEC2のMariaDBはsudo mysql_secure_installationの設定は行った方が良いでしょうか？

Comment: タイトルのキーワードで検索するだけでも方法が出てくるかと思いますが、これらは調べましたか？ 例: [MariaDB のデータを mysqldump でバックアップ・リストアする](https://blog.amedama.jp/entry/2015/08/30/225750)

Comment: この投稿には「ダンプの取得と復元によるデータ移行はどうするのか？」と「mysql_secure_installationの設定はすべきか？」という**二つの**質問が含まれています。質問が複数あると、一つだけに回答すると言うことが難しくなるため、スタック・オーバーフローでは一つの投稿で複数の質問をすることは推奨されません。質問をどちらか一つに絞り、もう一つは別の質問として投稿してください。